# NGINX Bad Gateway 502 on Any Port Except 3000 with NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, nginx, express

I have an NGINX instance (1.4 stable) in front of a few NodeJS instances.  I'm trying to load balance with NGINX using the upstream module like so:

```
upstream my_web_upstream {
          server localhost:3000;
          server localhost:8124;
          keepalive 64;
        }



location / {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
      proxy_set_header   Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_cache one;
      proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;
      proxy_pass         http://my_web_upstream;
        }
```

The problem occurs when the instance at port 3000 is not available.  I get a 502 Bad Gateway from NGINX.

If I change the upstream config to just point at one instance, 8124 for example, the 502 still occurs.

Running a netstat shows 0 other applications listening on any of the ports I've tried.

Why is NGINX reporting a bad gateway?  How can I get NGINX to do a fallthrough if one of the instances is down?

Comment: Are you sure your express backend is running properly? Do you get the correct content if you visit the upstream ports directly (`localhost:3000` and `localhost:8124`) ?

Comment: What's in the error_log?

Answer (score 0):

If netstat shows that your nodejs applications aren't running on the ports, then the problem is that you haven't started your nodejs applications.

This nginx config knows how to proxy to the nodejs application, but you are guaranteed to get a 502 if the nodejs application has not been started. If you want to run it on multiple ports, then you have to start the application on each port. So, don't hardcode port 3000 into the NodeJS code, but make it take the port from an environmental variable, or spawn multiple instances using a process manager like pm2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2). Once these are running, then nginx can proxy to them.